# "Read" function to Firebase DB is returning `Promise <pending>` object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making read request to my Firebase DB, but it keeps returning `Promise <pending>` object. I am relatively new to coding, so I appreciate the help :) - I just want to return the value (given by the path) in JSON format.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
let path7 = database.ref('CheckOuts/2)');

path7.once('value').then(function(elem) {
  let values = elem.val();
  return values;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let path7 = database.ref('CheckOuts/2)');

let result = await path7.once('value');

const value = snapshot.val();

console.log('result',value);
```

Make sure that `async` keyword properly added in the function